# Difference between 'max distance' and 'radius' in Physics.SphereCastAll

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting

I needed a way to check for all gameobjects within a set sphere of my player object.

I found Physics.SphereCastAll which will return a RaycastHit[], exactly what I wanted. But, I am having trouble understanding the method signature/docs.

Basically, it's the two things in the title I am confused on right now:

From Unity docs:

- radius    - The radius of the sphere.
- maxDistance - The max length of the sweep.

Is 'max length of the sweep' a measurement of time (or degrees?)? I would have thought the length would be the same as the radius (or at least you could calculate it from the radius) but it obviously isn't what I think length means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SphereCast` methods take a sphere and slide it along a line to see where it hits objects along its travel.

The `radius` parameter is the size of the sphere.

The `maxDistance` parameter is how far the sphere should travel in the given direction.

To simply check for objects near your player, you want [CheckSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html) or [OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) / [OverlapSphereNonAlloc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc.html) instead. These methods check for colliders intersecting a given sphere, and give you either a `bool` result of whether a collision was detected, or an array of the colliders overlapping the radius. They don't try to slide that sphere to find contact positions.

This is not equivalent to a `SphereCast` with a maxDistance of 0. Like a raycast, this will only detect the points where it begins to intersect with an object - not situations where it was already overlapping in its starting position.

Comment: is there much of a system impact difference between having the 0f maxDistance on SphereCast and the OverlapSphere. It seems id have to rewrite some code when I already have it working? thanks for your time as always

Comment: See the edit above. A SphereCast with maxDistance = 0 does not perform the job of checking for overlaps inside a radius. It's not a matter of performance - this method just doesn't return the kinds of results you're looking for.

Comment: ah, i understand now thanks. So if i used my existing method, and it the object was already inside my sphere at the start then it would never get detected. I will adjust the code to use Collider instead with the OverlapSphere. thanks muchly