# Count enemy inside Gizmos

Tags: unity

I'm trying to count the number of enemies inside Gizmos. Any enemy goes inside it count it ?

Here is my script:

```
public int enemy_around_me; // count enemies inside palyer orbit
public float player_orbit = 3;
private GameObject enemy;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
            enemy = GameObject.FindWithTag("enemy");

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

 void OnDrawGizmosSelected() {
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position, player_orbit);
}
```

Comment: You could use a Physics.SphereCast to get everything inside the sphere then use the Gizmo to just visualize it.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html

Comment: @Pheonix2105 [it's OverlapSphere you'll want, not SphereCast](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/158434/39518)

Comment: Woops, Sorry for that cheers!

Comment: Sorry, but It doesn't fit my script. What else could help me ?