# Unity3D: Multiple OnTriggerEnters are called before the first one could finish and destroy the object

Tags: unity, raycasting

I'm working on a **projectile** which **explodes** when it **reaches a destructible object** and **damages its voxels**. (The projectile is a *trigger*)

But the **problem** is that **I use raycasting** in `OnTriggerEnter` which makes it **slow to finish**. Which lets **multiple** `OnTriggerEnter` to be called before it could be **finally destroyed**.

I fixed it by having a **flag** which lets only one call to be executed. But it feels a bit *hacky*, so I decided to ask you, maybe you have **some better solutions**.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (!hit && LayerMask.LayerToName(collider.gameObject.layer) == "Destructible")
    {
        hit = true;
        DoImpact();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

void DoImpact()
{
    //Do ~1 SphereCast
    RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.SphereCastAll(transform.position, ExplosionRange, transform.forward, 0.0001f, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Destructible"));
    //Iterate through voxels
    foreach(var hit in hits)
    {
        //the parent object which manages its voxels
        var destructible = FindDestructibleParent(hit.transform); 
        //Make some damage to that voxel based on the projectile, the voxel, and some "whole container/parent object properties"
        destructible.TakeDamage(this, hit.transform.gameObject); 
    }
}
```

Comment: "I use raycasting in OnTriggerEnterwhich makes it slow to finish. Which lets multipleOnTriggerEnter to be called before it could be finally destroyed." Using raycasting in a method doesn't spread its execution across multiple frames or physics steps. It will still execute & complete in the same physics step it was called. That means if you're getting multiple OnTriggerEnter calls, it's because your trigger touched multiple objects in this one physics step. [Also, it looks like you might want OverlapSphere rather than SphereCastAll](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/158434/39518)

Comment: Yes, I already replaced it with OverlapSphere, thanks. And maybe yes, that's the case regarding the multiple calls. I will look into that. Thanks again :)