# Only do 1 SphereCastAll in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, raycasting

I just want to make **one SphereCastAll** with a center and a radius.

I don't want unnecessary sweeping in a desired direction with a desired length. How is this achievable? My solution is pretty unreliable, I think.

```
var hits = Physics.SphereCastAll(center, radius, forward, 0.0001f, mask);
```

Comment: Are you looking for the OverlapSphere method? [See this answer for details on how they differ](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/158434/39518)

Comment: Yes, I do, thanks for the quick help. For some reason I couldn't think about any other name for this functionality than SphereCast.